# How to find the reason behind sudden CPU max usage and server crash

Tags: 20.04, apache2, cpu-load

Scenario:
I have a 4 core CPU, 8GB Ram, Ubuntu 20.04 server with [Linode.com](https://linode.com). For the last few days my linode console shows a 400% CPU usage statistics and sends me threshold exceed warning emails.

**Many linode users seems to have this high CPU usage issue and there are many posts in linode forums and other sites but I wasn't able to figure out the the reason behind this, with their suggestions and answers.**

As per forum answers I run the **HTOP** command, **TOP** command etc and got the following results.
As I am not much familiar with Ubuntu I can't figure out what is "`ssd: root@pts/1`" command is and why it consumes too much CPU.

**HTOP** : [image: this]

Also I can't figure out what does those the first 5 processes are and why they causing the high CPU usage.

Can any one point me to find what process is run by those commands?.

Info :

1. As it is a testing server, there is no considerable traffic at any point.(Maximum 1-2 users)(issue still there even when there is no traffic)
2. Apache access log and error log doesn't show any issues.

The **who** command returns:

```
abin     pts/0        2021-02-09 20:26 (xxx.xxx.xxx.xx)
abin     pts/1 2021-02-09 18:37 (xxx.xxx.xxx.xx)
abin     pts/2        2021-02-09 20:10 (xxx.xxx.xxx.xx)
```

**/etc/crontab**:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
```

**top**[image: top]

I have tried [this](https://www.linode.com/community/questions/17025/investigate-the-cause-of-high-cpu-usage) forum suggestion and reduced the swappiness to a lower value. But it doesn't helped either.

If any additional data needed, let me know.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Edit:
`ps -eo user=|sort|uniq -c` :

```
7 abin
1 daemon
1 messagebus
1 mysql
114 root
1 sshd
1 syslog
1 systemd-network
1 systemd-resolve
1 systemd-timesync
355 www-data
```

and many processes are cumulating in 'www-data'

Additional Info:

1. There are too many login attempt logs in `/var/log/auth.log`.
2. `var/log/syslog`. [please note after Feb 18 11:41:50 there is not log until Feb 18 17:12:48]

```
Feb 18 11:41:50 ubuntu-xxx kernel: [758663.561513] oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_NONE,nodemask=(null),cpuset=/,mems_allowed=0,global_oom,task_memcg=/system.s>
Feb 18 11:41:50 ubuntu-xxx kernel: [758663.561525] Out of memory: Killed process 422931 (pgrep) total-vm:755444kB, anon-rss:500260kB, file-rss:2196kB, shmem-r>
Feb 18 11:41:50 ubuntu-xxx kernel: [758663.720846] oom_reaper: reaped process 422931 (pgrep), now anon-rss:0kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
Feb 18 17:12:48 ubuntu-xxx kernel: [758718.889366] [ 365827]    33 365827     2191     1266    57344       36             0 bash
```

Comment: Are you using Apache Mina SSHD? That appears to be the issue 

Comment: How to check is it installed or enabled? How to disable it? Is any alternatives available?

Comment: There are too many questions there for me to answer without knowing more about the server, it's configuration, and what it's used for, which I'm not particularly interested in knowing. Apache Mina is a network application framework that offers a bunch of tools, such as an FTP server, an XMPP (ugh!) server, an alternative SSH server, a bunch of Java helpers, and the like. You may be able to lower CPU usage with a `sudo service apache2 restart`, as that should kill any running processes but, again, it really comes down to how the server is configured.

Comment: Really sorry about the ignorance. I am not aware about the server configurations. I have followed [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-20-04) and [this](https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/how-to-install-a-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-18-04/). I haven't changed no other config. This server is used as a testing server 3-4 php applications.

Comment: `ps -eo user=|sort|uniq -c` command return :`7 abin      1 daemon      1 messagebus      1 mysql    114 root      1 sshd      1 syslog      1 systemd-network      1 systemd-resolve      1 systemd-timesync    355 www-data`

Answer (score 0):

First of all replace you real IP Address by some dummy IP in question.

Try to change default ssh port on server.
Create file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/01-port.conf` with line (21412 port only for example, you can use any port from range 1024-65535)

```
Port 21412
```

restart sshd

```
systemctl restart sshd
```

Don't logout from server till you test login to server with new ssh port in another terminal.

To ssh login with new port use

```
ssh -p 21412 user@yourserver
```

Comment: How to check if the port 21412 (or xxxx) allowed in firewall?

Comment: `sudo ufw status verbose` or dump iptables `sudo iptables -vL`

Comment: shall I add the result for `sudo ufw status verbose` to the question?

Comment: No. Just change port follow by answer. In terminal try to start new connecion with new port, that's enough. if someone goes wrong you can revert changes in exists connecton.